# Plain Servlet vs Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, web-applications

I have to create a web application, I need to use my back-end code for mobile apps also.

I know Servlet, I thought of doing this application with "REST API" + HIBERNATE for server side and Javascript(Angular JS ) in UI.

Some of my colleagues suggest to do this with Spring. I don't know anything about Spring. While reading about Spring I came to know that back-end logic and UI code can be in same place. It seems it is tightly coupled with back-end and front-end.

Some times back Jquery is more preferable JS framework but now everyone suggests Angular JS. This will be changed after some times. But logic I am going to write in back-end will be the same.

How can I choose the correct one?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use:

- Spring web MVC for backend https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/, maybe with Spring Boot, and Hibernate for DAO layer. Here you can find a helpful example (without Spring Boot): http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-and-spring-security-4-integration-example/
- and for frontend certainly Angular 2, with TypeScript, instead of Angular js, and here reach the REST service exposed by backend.

Answer (score -1):

These days it is easy to build a REST based back end with *no libraries at all* if you deploy to a Java EE 6/7 server such as WildFly, TomEE or Payara (amongst others).

You get JAX-RS and JSON-P (for rest), JPA for persistence, web sockets, asynchronous processing, transaction management and the rest of the Java EE stack for free.

Try a google search for `Java EE thin war` - there's lots of examples about